# How can I grep or awk everything in this text file that corresponds to what I need?

Tags: awk, grep

Hey so I have a log file with all these bytes.
I want to only grep or awk every line that has over the number 499 in it and put it into a text file.

Here is an example.

```
Wed Dec  3 12:52:05 2014; UDP; eth1; 32 bytes; from 197.46.140.50:1434
Wed Dec  3 12:52:05 2014; UDP; eth1; 32 bytes; from 197.46.140.50:1434
Wed Dec  3 12:52:05 2014; UDP; eth1; 652 bytes; from 197.46.140.50:1434 
Wed Dec  3 12:52:05 2014; UDP; eth1; 32 bytes; from 197.46.140.50:1434 
Wed Dec  3 12:52:05 2014; UDP; eth1; 32 bytes; from 197.46.140.50:1434 
Wed Dec  3 12:52:05 2014; UDP; eth1; 122 bytes; from 197.46.140.50:1434
Wed Dec  3 12:52:05 2014; UDP; eth1; 32 bytes; from 197.46.140.50:1434
Wed Dec  3 12:52:05 2014; UDP; eth1; 32 bytes; from 197.46.140.50:1434 
Wed Dec  3 12:52:05 2014; UDP; eth1; 885 bytes; from 197.46.140.50:1434
```

I want only

```
Wed Dec  3 12:52:05 2014; UDP; eth1; 885 bytes; from 197.46.140.50:1434 
Wed Dec  3 12:52:05 2014; UDP; eth1; 652 bytes; from 197.46.140.50:1434
```

put into a text file. Anything over 499 bytes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try doing this :

```
$ awk '$8 > 499' file > another_text_file
```

No need to add `print`, `awk` already print on a `TRUE` condition.

`grep` is not the right tool here.